# Can we use useState() at multiple time or is there any limit to use it in React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, new-operator

Can we use useState() at multiple time or is there any limit to use it in single component in React Js.

Comment: You can call it as many times as you like, as long as you follow the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

Comment: If there's any kind of limit, it's going to be based on available resources and unrelated to the `useState` hook itself.  More to the point, what happens when you *try*?  Do you encounter any kind of problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `useState` multiple times. In fact it's even recommended in the React docs.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables

> we recommend to split state into multiple state variables based on which values tend to change together.

I am not aware of any limit to its use.